# Детский вопрос: есть ли однокоренные глаголы со словами «маг» и «волшебник»?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, глаголы

Девочка (второй класс) изучает синонимы: колдун, маг, волшебник, чародей.
Выстроили цепочку: колдун — колдовство — колдовать.
Любознательный ребенок через некоторое время спросил: "А как будут **другие** *действия предмета*?"
С чародеем разобрались.
Волшебник — волшебство — ?
Маг — магия — ?
Подскажите, имеются ли такие глаголы?

Comment: Маг - заимствованное слово, поэтому без глагола. Волшебник произошел от волхва вроде. Да вот только глагол опять позабыли. Волховать остался в прошлом, а в настоящем используется по-факту только один глагол "колдовать" и 4-е существительных: Маг, Колдун, Волшебник, Чародей

Comment: Когда-то имел место глагол «волшебничать». Иногда встречается и сейчас. Есть у Тихонова в «Словообразовательном словаре».

Comment: Девочка изучает именно эти синонимы? Мага (перс. жрец, астролог, гадатель) могла бы заменить гадалка...

Comment: Еще одно слово в тематический словарь (из Д. Емеца): "Я великий магический волшебник! Этот вот крупный человек мотоциклетного вида мой слуга. Он одинокий тундровый шаман, занимающийся промышленным отстрелом парапсихологов....Эти вот двое — с топором и шестом — служители зла, вредители-недоучки, выращиватели зимних чихов, которых даже в гаишной машине отказались везти — так они мелки и ничтожны...Ну а теперь расскажи о себе! У тебя мощное КОЛДУВАЧЕСТВО? Откуда у тебя Карта Хаоса?

Comment: http://www.slavdict.ru/_0092.htm  Волшебство = волжба — волхвователь — волхнующий (прорицатель) — волхвовати. ============ ВОЛХВОВАТЬ, -вую, -вуешь; нсв. Заниматься гаданием, предсказаниями, чародейством. < Волхвование, -я. (ГРАМОТА.РУ – справочно-информационный...
gramota.ru›dic)

Comment: Ребенку, собственно, нужно было подобрать синоним к слову "колдун". Она назвала: волшебник. Я добавила: маг, чародей. Не стоит ведь довольствоваться только одним словом, правда? Кудесник, чудесник, ворожей, волхв — эти слова я предусмотрительно не озвучивала (слишком много объяснять).

Comment: @slava1947 Нашла с Вашей помощью: Он должен возить пассажиров, а не волшебничать! [Леонид Сапожников. Митя Метелкин в Стране Синих роз (1988)] Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

От "Мага" дети легко образуют *мажествовать* (встречается в разных там фанфиках по Гарри Поттеру).
От "Волшебника" - *волшебничать*, уже сказали.

Но вопрос=то не в этом.
Разве детей учат, что от любого слова (в данном случая - от любого члена ряда существительных-синонимов) всегда можно образовать глагол?

Comment: Не думаю, что **восьмилетним** детям объясняют, что не от каждого слова можно образовать глагол. Да они и слова-то такого еще не знают, оперируют пока понятием "действие предмета". Я именно такую формулировку и дала в вопросе. А девочка назвала (по аналогии, предполагаю) такие глаголы: _магить, магствовать, волшебить, волшебствовать_. Мажествовать? Нет, таких ассоциаций у второклассницы не возникло. P. S. Мы сейчас учимся дома — рыскать некогда. Я сказала, что не знаю таких слов, и пообещала, что спрошу у тех, кто знает. Извините, что попросила помощи.  P. P. S. Поясните, в чем некорректность?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова *Не думаю, что восьмилетним детям объясняют, что не от каждого слова можно образовать глагол* - Вы подменяете понятия. От того, что "детям не объясняют..." большой беды не будет. Не объясняют - и ладно. Давайте от печки. В каком учебнике/пособии сказано что-то подобное тому, что вы в вопрос вставили? То есть требование обязательного существования глагола от подобных существительных?

Comment: *Поясните, в чем некорректность* - именно в этом. В том, что вы неявно (а теперь уже и явно) требуете существования глагола по существительному.

Comment: Я ничего не требовала и никаких понятий не подменяла. И теперь уже сожалею, что сдуру попросила помощи на форуме. Дети, к великому сожалению (или к радости — не знаю), задают очень много вопросов, на которые нужно отвечать, а не отмахиваться. P. S. Если же Вы посчитали мой вопрос некорректным, то могли бы его и поправить (с Вашим-то опытом!). Пожалуй, сделаю это сама.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова *Я ничего не требовала* - В таком случае ваш вопрос лишен смысла. Если вы не требуете существования подобного глагола, то в чем смысл вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю вопрос. Если есть «апельсин», то должно быть «апельсинничать» или что? Почему такие слова должны быть?
У «колдовство» есть такое слов, потому что оно, скорее всего, произошло от «колдовать». Не все существительные, внезапно, происходят от глаголов, поэтому не у всех существительных будут такого рода родственники. А если они и есть, то могут перестать употребляться и исчезнуть из языка.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/38021)

Comment: Вы вместо ответа на вопрос (согласен, не совсем корректно заданный) хотите вступить в полемику с автором. Зачем?!

Comment: Мой ответ заключался в том, что таких слов нет и не должно быть; ваш ответ заключался примерно в том же. Единственное отличие в том, что мой ответ чуть более дерзок и вызывающ. Меня обижали, когда я был юн, и я не мог ответить обидчику. Теперь я повсюду вижу несправедливость, несмотря на то, что обидчика, возможно, уже нет в живых. Из защитных мотивов я постоянно нападаю на всех.

Comment: А со мной тем более не надо спорить.